# Adding scrollbar to floating form

Tags: jquery, html, forms, jquery-plugins, scrollbar

I have a registration form that is just a floating container on the front page. I want to add a scrollbar to it but for some reason it is not working. I am using this scrollbar [plugin](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller). Here's is my code: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6ak6/)

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Well for a start you had the form set to display: none ...

Comment: @David Yes I know, I do a show() when the user selects a certain option. That's not the problem. The problem is the form shows but there is no scrollbar

Comment: You need to set a height for the form element and also: `overflow: auto;` like so: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6ak6/1/

Comment: @David yes but that defeats the purpose of using a plugin. I want a customized scrollbar not the default one.

Comment: You have to have those CSS properties set for the plugin to work, check out his demos to see for yourself! It even states so on the page that you linked to the plugin.

Comment: @David ah okay, can I add the scrollbar to the form rather than the div container?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17084/discussion-between-david-and-richard)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a height on the element you are applying the scrollbar too, and to also make sure overflow: auto; is set.

A working example can be found: http://pastebin.com/VsDHRZtd (jsfiddle would not work, I got it working with just this code on localhost), make sure the files are in their relevant places too as per the file.

Enjoy :)

Comment: Still not working. I think it might be the version of jquery. Does it have to be 1.7(jquery) and 1.8(jquery ui)?

Comment: It may well have to be those. Give it a go.